# SQL Server - Archiving Data (Strategy/Stored Procedure)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently we have 100+ databases, some about 10GB in size with millions of records and they are growing at an alarming rate. We need to evaluate our archiving strategy.

Does anyone have any suggestions and sample scripts that go through all the tables and archives the data into an ARCHIVED database - with everything being audited (in regards to number of records imported etc..) and in case of failure it rolls back everything?

Regards

Comment: 100+? Tables? Kilobytes? Records? Giraffes?

Comment: Mainly archiving is critical for 10+ database - Size: 978 GB Number of Records: Already in millions on all database. Number of Tables in each database: 15-25

Comment: Data structure? Any existing data redundancy methods in place? Like mirroring or replication? Also, what version of sql-server?

Comment: Verison of SQL Server: 2005. No mirroring or replication. For all the tables - we have one common field (ImportDate) - which we can used for archiving. No data redundancy methods in place.

Comment: Maybe these can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607653/sql-archive-script http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189258.aspx http://vyaskn.tripod.com/sql_archive_data.htm

Comment: What version of SQL Server 2005 do you have? Standard? Enterprise? If you have enterprise you could research using partition swapping. Partitioning by something like a date field, then swapping out older partitions from the table to an archive version of the table. [Here](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-decide-if-should-use-table-partitioning/) is a good article about partitioning  in case you have Enterprise and you're interested.

Comment: Refer the below link

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/25/sql-server-2005-database-table-partitioning-tutorial-how-to-horizontal-partition-database-table/

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning can help a lot to archive within single database. Sliding window scenario is a particular tool.

Let me suggest setting up an Admin database. It will handle all setting and information about archiving.

There may be 2 SQL Server instances: Current Server and Archive Server. They will have same structure.

Process copies data from remote server to archive server using settings from Admin DB. There may be need in writing Dynamic SQL. Check [Sp_MSForEachDB](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/).

Answer (score 0):

+1 to partitioning idea. To add - I think you can use it also if you have Developers edition

Comment: You should place this as a comment to Stoleg's answer

Comment: I don't see a way to add comments to main topic